# Why isn't my glm test running in R studio?

Tags: r, glm

I am new to R. I am trying to run a glm test. I have uploaded the data that was a CVS and converted using the str() function. I have also tried the function as.numeric() for the satisfactory and unsatisfactory variables. I have attached screenshots.

[image]

Comment: Because you are trying to apply a logistic regression, which requires the dependent (outcome) variable to be either a 0 (or FALSE) or a 1 (or TRUE).

Comment: If you want to perform a logisitc regression, your response variable needs be between 0 and 1 as the error message indicates. You are using `Satisfied` as the response and that variables has values of 288, 60, 244 etc which are clearly not between 0 and 1.  Those aren't probabilities. Maybe you meant `glm(cbind(Satisfied, Unsatisfied) ~ ., family=binomial, data=dat)`  which is the special form to calculate percentages for you.